# MySQL query and indexing

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with street address data, containing ~14 million records. I am trying to search and for the purpose of it, I have created few indexes. The query that I am running is :

```
SELECT * 
   from ADDRESSES 
   WHERE number_first = 538 
     AND street_name IN ('COLL', 'COLLA', 'COLLABY HILL', 'COLLACE', 
         'COLLAERY','COLLANDA','COLLANILLING','COLLARD','COLLARE',
         '[plus about another 100+ street names]' )
     AND locality_name in ('MERRIMAC', 'ST ANDREWS', 'WARWICK', 'HORSHAM', 
        'WARNERTOWN','BRUNSWICK','FAIRY MEADOW','RUSSELL VALE', 'CARRAMAR',
         '[plus about another 500+ locality names]' )
```

I have created an index on street_name and number_first as following:  (`street_name`(4),`number_first`)

As locality_name is also included in the query, I created another index as following:
(`number_first`,`street_name`,`locality_name`)

Running EXPLAIN on the SELECT query always chooses the first index and not the second one. How can I modify my query/index so that I can search on the basis of street_name, locality_name and number_first.

PS: The MySQL version that I am using is 5.5.45

Comment: Why do you want to use a specific index? Are you sure you know better than the database engine that it would result in a faster execution? Sometimes using an index is slower than not using it.

Comment: I just want to understand that why the index that has street_name and locality_name is overridden in the favour of the one with only partial street_name

Comment: I suspect number_first will have lesser value variations. Likely a new index of `street_name,locality_name,number_first` will be.

Comment: You could store the respective arrays in 'temporary' indexed tables

Comment: @Strawberry - Can you please elaborate a bit more? Thanks

Comment: @ajreal - I changed the order of the columns in the index, still no change.

Answer (score 0):

because it is recombination index.
recombination index(the left matching)
That's why it only matches the first one index

Answer (score 0):

Consider the following:

```
CREATE TABLE addresses
(id INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY
,number_first INT NOT NULL
,street_name INT NOT NULL
,locality_name INT NOT NULL
,INDEX(number_first,street_name,locality_name)
);

CREATE TABLE temp_streetname(streetname INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

CREATE TABLE temp_localityname(localityname INT NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY);

SELECT COUNT(0) FROM addresses;
+----------+
| COUNT(0) |
+----------+
|  4194304 |
+----------+

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_streetname;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|      117 |
+----------+

SELECT COUNT(*) FROM temp_localityname;
+----------+
| COUNT(*) |
+----------+
|      563 |
+----------+

SELECT a.* 
  FROM addresses a 
  JOIN temp_localityname x 
    ON x.localityname = a.locality_name 
  JOIN temp_streetname y 
    ON y.streetname = a.street_name 
 WHERE a.number_first = 538;
+---------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| id      | number_first | street_name | locality_name |
+---------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
| 1910930 |          538 |        1287 |           829 |
| 2964907 |          538 |        1322 |          1001 |
+---------+--------------+-------------+---------------+
2 rows in set (0.04 sec)
```

So here we have an addresses table comprising 4 million rows, with a composite index on (number_first,street_name,locality_name).

We also have 'temporary' tables of streetnames and localities comprising 117 and 563 rows respectively. (I mean 'temporary' in the sense that I don't intend to keep them for very long, rather than the more technical sense).

I've populated all the tables with random integers - but the principle is the same, regardless of data type.

As you can see, the query executed against these tables takes just under half a second.